# Non aborting assertion CppUnit

Tags: c++, qt, cppunit

I'm using multiple assertions in a testfunction but when (for instance) the first one fails the rest of the assertions isn't executed anymore.
Is there a way to make an assertion (CPPUNIT_ASSERT) with CppUnit that doesn't leave the testfunction after failing? e.g. non aborting assertion.

I have found this: http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/cppunit2/doc/ but a "CHECK" isn't implemented in the library.

Comment: Did you try CPPUT_CHECK rather than CPPUNIT_CHECK?

Comment: Yes I did, but it isn't included

Comment: This seems like a very bad practice. Your test should either fail or pass, doesn't matter on which assert. If the reason it fails is unclear, then you should refactor the test instead of trying to make a handicapped assert...

Comment: Hi BartoszKP, re-factoring was my second(last) option. But I was looking for a workaround to reduce the number of separated tests. CppUnit shows the assertion that fails and that is enough information for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are two schools of thought on unit tests. One is that a unit test should test one thing only, and that if you wish to test two things, you should have two tests. The advantage is that the problem you describe above is completely eliminated, while the disadvantage is that it takes a few extra seconds to write an additional test. The other idea is that a test can test multiple things, with the idea that a failing test is infrequent, and can be recognized by the developer and fixed. The advantage is that a complex setup needs to be done only one time, and of course the disadvantage is that it stops testing at the first failure, hiding the true number and identity of problems.

My approach is to be pragmatic. If you can get away with multiple assertions, and still develop and easily test multiple attributes with one test, do it -- but be prepared for failure, and if you get stuck in the situation you describe, quickly refactor the test into multiple tests and do NOT waste time struggling with the one test. The overall number of tests is absolutely a non-factor. The appropriate number of tests is the number you need to thoroughly assess your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. It seems like that there is no workaround so I will separate my tests more.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CPPUNIT_VFY(cond) as defined below instead of using CPPUNIT_ASSERT(cond):

```
#define CPPUNIT_VFY(cond) {\
    try { \
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT(cond); \
    } catch(std::exception& e) { \
        std::cerr << ">>>> EXCEPTION:<" << __LINE__ << ":" << ++xcount << "> " << e.what() << std::endl; \
    } }
```

You need to declare xcount in your CppUnit derived test class and initialize it in the setup() method. This prints the incremented failure counts.
The above macro will print all the assertions without exiting on the first failure, e.g.

```
>>>> EXCEPTION:<140:1> assertion failed
- Expression <whatever>  
>>>> EXCEPTION:<163:2> assertion failed
- Expression <whatever>
etc.
```

Refer the numbers above within <> above. The left side is the line number where the assertion failed, the right side is the fail count.